# Make Sqlalchemy Use Date In Filter Using Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to perform the following query in Sqlalchemy.

```
Select * from "Mytable" where Date(date_time_field) = "2011-08-16";
```

I have tried several methods. Some here on SO.
But none seems "realistic" since some do Casts Other String Formating ?!?! and not a plain simple Date() *( By Date i Mean the Postgresql Date not the Python One)* at the ORM Field.

Is it possible at the ORM level to declare a Simple `Date()` around the queried field?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To keep it clean for any web search.

```
from sqlalchemy import Date, cast
from datetime import date

my_data = session.query(MyObject).\
filter(cast(MyObject.date_time,Date) == date.today()).all()
```

Comment: From my experience `func.date` is better if you use SQLite for testing, as `cast` does not work.

Answer (score 28):

Native SQL functions can be invoked using using [`func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html) module

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from datetime import date

my_data = session.query(MyObject).filter(
    func.date(MyObject.date_time) == date.today()
).all()
```

Calling `func.date`

```
 from sqlalchemy import select, func
 print select([func.date('2004-10-19 10:23:54')])
```

will produce following SQL:

```
 SELECT date(:date_2) AS date_1
```

You can also declare your own shortcuts to SQL functions:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import GenericFunction
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime

class convert_tz(GenericFunction):
    """
    Sqlalchemy shortcut to SQL convert timezone function

    :param DateTime datetime
    :param str from_tz: The timezone the datetime will be converted from
    :param str to_tz: The timezone the datetime will be converted from
    :returns: Datetime in another timezone
    :rtype: DateTime or None if timezones are invalid

    """
    type = DateTime
```

Used like:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func
print select([func.convert_tz(func.now(), '+00:00', '-05:00')])
```

It will generate following SQL:

```
SELECT convert_tz(now(), :param_1, :param_2) AS convert_tz_1
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: I added explanations and reference to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

in postgreSQL if date_time_field is one field of your table then quer must like this.
Select * from Mytable where date_time_field = '2011-08-16'

Comment: Hello , well more precisely the field is timestamp with no timezone :)

Comment: The easy way is to just cast it to date, select * from mytable where cast(date_time_field as date)='2011-08-16';  shorthand for casting in pgsql is the :: method like so: select * from mytable where date_time_field::date='2011-08-16'; but that's not SQL spec standard and won't be portable.  If you don't need portable then the :: method is much cleaner looking and easier to remember the syntax as well.  However your method with the date(date_time_field) should work as well.

Comment: Hello Scott , thank now the problem is actually porting this into Sqlalchemy , i will give it a try today :)

Comment: Easy: cast(MyObj.date_time_field, Date) == date.today()

Answer (score 1):

Here are generic solution that also works in SQLite:

```
day = date.today()
next_day = day + timedelta(days=1)
my_data = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.date_time >= day,  MyObject.date_time < next_day).all()
```