# How to filter datetime.utcnow() to a specific date.today() in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an `Order` Object with a `created_on` field.

```
created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

Now I was trying to get the number of order created in a day by using the `number_of_order_a_day` function:

```
@classmethod
def number_of_order_a_day(cls):
    return cls.query.filter(cls.created_on.like('%{}'.format(date.today()))).count()
```

But the function returns `0`.

This is my `OrderModel` Class:

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime, date
from app import db



class OrderModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "orders"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    order_number = db.Column(db.String(80))
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())


    def __init__(self, order_number, created_on):
        self.order_number = order_number
        self.created_on = created_on


    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, id):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id = id).first() 

    @classmethod
    def find_by_order_number(cls, order_number):
        return cls.query.filter_by(order_number = order_number).first() 

    @classmethod
    def number_of_order_a_day(cls):
        return cls.query.filter(cls.created_on.like('{}'.format(date.today()))).count()


    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def delete_from_db(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä, Each and every Order has a gets the time and the date which it was created. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow. I am using sqlite for development. Planing to use mysql for prod.

Comment: The answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075828/make-sqlalchemy-use-date-in-filter-using-postgresql apply to your filtering situation, even if the title is "...using PostgreSQL". In case of SQLite the SQL function `DATE()` is the better option, I think.

Comment: Actually my question is to how do I filter the datetime.utcnow() field with only by date.today(). Am I using the function cls.created_on.like('{}'.format(date.today()) currently?

Comment: You are using it, but you shouldn't. Read the answers from the linked Q/A, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/24760540/2681632. In SQLite you want to use `DATE()` function, because `DATE` typename has numeric affinity and `CAST(created_on AS DATE)` will not do what you maybe would expect it to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211738/discussion-between-reactive-learner-and-ilja-everila).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was like the following importing `func` from `sqlalchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
```

Then the `number_of_order_a_day` function

```
@classmethod
def number_of_order_a_day(cls):
    return cls.query.filter(func.DATE(cls.created_on) == datetime.utcnow().date()).all()
```

Instead of `count()` I am returning all the matching orders as a list by date. Then in the order resource page getting `number_of_order_a_day` by using the `len()` function for the list :

```
number_of_order_a_day = len(OrderModel.number_of_order_a_day())
```

I have found `count()` to be a bit slow.